# The difference of normal means is also minimax?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, minimax

Let $X_i \sim N(\xi, \sigma^2)$ and $Y_i \sim N(\eta, \tau^2)$ for **known** $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$.

I know that $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are minimax under squared error loss since their variance is fixed, and a sequence of Bayes estimators can be constructed such that their Bayes risk converge to the maximum risk of $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$.

I am wondering how I can show $\delta(X,Y) =\bar{Y}-\bar{X}$ is also minimax for $\eta-\xi$?

Essentially I need to show that for any $T(X,Y)$, we have

$$\sup_{\xi,\eta} E(T(X,Y)-(\eta-\xi))^2 \leq \sup_{\eta,\xi} E((\bar{Y}-\bar{X})-(\eta-\xi))^2 = \frac{\sigma^2+\tau^2}{n}$$

The only thing I can think of doing is constructing another sequence of priors whose Bayes risks converge to the RHS. However, this seems kind of tedious now that we're in 2 dimensions. I feel like there's a "trick" here that I should be using?

Comment: It looks to me that for any permutation $\sigma,$ the sequence $Y_i-X_{\sigma(i)}$ is an iid sample from $N(\eta-\xi, \tau^2+\sigma^2)$ under the implicit assumptions of (1) independence of all $X_i$ and $Y_j$ and (2) equinumerous datasets.  Apply your assertion (after "I know") to this sequence.

Comment: I concur with @whuber that the problem is identical to a single Normal problem

Comment: I understand why it would be minimax for a dataset $(X_i-Y_i)$, and I also understand how all permutations $\sigma(i)$ would give an equivalent distribution. But doesn't this assume the minimax estimator is of the form $g(X_i-Y_i)$? What about other linear estimators $g(aX_i-bY_i)$  etc? If that makes sense

Comment: It makes sense.  The concept of *sufficient statistic* is at the bottom of this: a sufficient statistic for $\eta-\xi$ is $\bar Y-\bar X;$ apart from nonzero multiples of this, no other linear combination is sufficient.  The proof lies in examining the likelihood function.